# Count the sum of the difference between rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

How do I calculate the difference between each row and return the total sum and also how to write it in a procedure.(I use **mysql**)

(There will be gaps in the id column)

```
id --- session --- value
1.........3..........15
4.........3...........5
7.........3...........8
10........3..........13
11........3...........9
```

From id.1 to id.4 difference is **10**
From id.2 to id.3 difference is **3**
From id.3 to id.4 difference is **5**
From id.4 to id.5 difference is **4**
The total sum is = **22**

This is what I have come up with: (and yes its completely wrong)

```
SET @oldV = 0;

SELECT SUM(table.x)
FROM(
    SELECT @oldV := value AND IF(value > @oldV, @x:=(value - @oldV), @x:=(@oldV - value)) x
    FROM TheTable WHERE session = 3 ORDER BY id) table;
```

Comment: Show us your effort. Have you tried anything? or this is just homework?

Comment: You can't do this with single query. You have to use some backend programming for this.

Comment: Are `id`s an uninterrupted sequence?

Comment: There will problobly be gaps in the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of ways to obtain the specified result.

One possibility (specific to MySQL) is to use a user-defined variable to store the "value" from the previous row, so you can compare that to the "value" from the current row.

Note: the behavior of MySQL user-defined variables in a statement like the one below is undefined. The MySQL Reference Manual warns against depending on the behavior of user-defined variables in a context like this. BUT... we do observe repeatable consistent behavior in MySQL 5.1 and 5.5.

```
SELECT SUM(d.diff) AS tot_diff
  FROM ( SELECT ABS(t.`value`-@pvalue) AS diff
              , @pvalue := t.`value`
           FROM mytable t
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT @pvalue := NULL ) i
          ORDER BY t.id
       ) d
```

Note that it's important that the user-defined variable be initialized, since the variable persists for the session, not just the statement. That's why we include the initialization in an inline view (derived table *i*). Optionally, we could run a separate `SET @pvalue := NULL;` statement before we run the query.

Comment: I like your idea but I get an error "...right syntax to use near 'END'". I create the code in a procedure and I dont think there is anything wrong with the procedure. Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: @user3800924: within a MySQL stored program, statements need to be terminated with a semicolon. If you include a bare SELECT statement (like the one above) within a procedure, the resultset will be returned to the client. If you don't want to return the resultset, you'll need to do something else with the row that is returned, for example, `SELECT ... INTO`, `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, declare/open/fetch from a cursor, etc,

Comment: @user3800924: It looks like I missed a predicate that you specified in your original query... `session = 3`. If you need that, modify the query above by adding **`WHERE t.session = 3`** before the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 3):

based on your example you seem to be calculating the absolute difference between rows.  You can do this with a join statement.  Try something like the following:

```
select a.id,b.id,abs(a.value - b.value) as dif
from UserData as a 
inner join
UserData as b
on a.id = b.id - 1
```

then once you have the dif col you can do a sum.  If there are going to be gaps in the id create a new col ROWNUMBER which has no gaps and then use that instead of id as your on statement

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4573/5

```
SELECT *, 
   IF(@prev IS NULL,0, @diff := ABS(`value`-@prev)),
      @prev:=`value`,
      @total:=IF(@total IS NULL,0,@total)+@diff
FROM table1
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: This one is really good but how do I only return the total value?

Answer (score 1):

I do not like it very much, but it seems to work.

```
SELECT 
   SUM(
       ABS(t1.num - t2.num)
   ) AS sumofdiffs
   FROM sumdiff AS t1 
   JOIN sumdiff AS t2 
      ON(
          (SELECT MIN(id) FROM sumdiff AS t3 WHERE t3.id > t1.id) = t2.id
      )
;
```

Found another way. Using just a subquery, no joins. It still is rather slow. But should be better thant the first query.

```
SELECT 
    SUM( 
        ABS( t1.num - 
            (SELECT num FROM sumdiff WHERE id > t1.id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 ) 
        )
    ) AS summofdiffs
FROM sumdiff AS t1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f46d8/19)

Comment: @user3800924 no problem. just keep in mind it's very slow (tried mine on 2mio rows ... 9 hours and still running) and other solutions will probably be faster. (though maybe it's my something somewhere)

Comment: 40 hours and still running :D Not very effective.

Comment: 9 days and counting :D

Comment: okay. killed it after 25 days. guess that is really really inefficient way to do the summing :)