# Get the Sum of negative differences between each row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

How do I calculate the negative difference between each row and return as a total sum?

For example (col "fictional difference" is only for better understanding):

| id | value | fictional difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 63 | 0 -> ignrore |
| 1 | 61 | -2 |
| 2 | 55 | -6 |
| 3 | 62 | +7 -> ignore |
| 4 | 57 | -5 |
| 5 | 71 | +14 -> ignore |

The goal would be the absolute sum of all negative differences: 13.

Has anybody an idea how to achieve this?
I've tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29779698/12350648 but it doesn't work for my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(if(valuediff<0,-valuediff,0))
from (
    select value-lag(value) over (order by id) as valuediff
    from mysterytablename
) valuediff
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not saying this is the best solution, but I took the example which didn't work for you and rebuild it slightly into this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(`diff` >= 0, 0, `diff`)) FROM (
    SELECT 
        IF(@prev IS NULL, 0, @diff := `value` - @prev) AS `diff`,
        @prev := `value`
    FROM table1
    ORDER BY id
) AS `diffTable`
```

The inner SELECT builds a table with the difference called `diffTable` and then the outer SELECT sums the negative results.

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62bc4d/12

Comment: Oh, it should be the absolute sum, I think you can manage that.

Comment: @SebastianNeugebauer Actually, I think the solution of "ysth", using `LAG() OVER` is the more elegant one. And the `JOIN` solution by "blabla_bingo" is also a great idea. But in the end they all perform the same task. It's nice to see there are many ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: setting variables in select is deprecated in mysql 8 and may be removed in some future version, so for mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2+ the lag version should be used, while for older versions (that don't suport lag) this approach should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a table join to achieve this.

```
select abs(sum(diff)) as abs_diff
from (select if(t2.value-t1.value<0,t2.value-t1.value,0) as diff 
    from test t1
    join test t2
    on t2.id=t1.id+1) t
;
-- result set:
13
```